# How to create a dictionary of arrays to strings in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary that maps a specific array like [1,1,0,0] to a string 'Car' but the dictionary does not accept arrays or lists

```
a={(1,1,0,0):'Car',
(0,0,0,1):'Pedestrian',    
(1,0,0,0):'Traffic Light'}

b=np.array([[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]])
```

Both codes are free of errors but obviously they don't match. Here is my idea:

```
b.map(a)

Out[3]=['Car','Traffic Light','Pedestrian']
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A dict key *must* be an immutable type; that's why tuples work, but lists don't.

Comment: Yes, `dict` objects cannot have `list` or `np.array` objects as keys. Perhaps `tuple(my_list)` as a key?

Comment: It looks like your dict + array solution will work, once you use `map` as defined.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Also, `np.ndarray` objects don't have a `.map` method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple *list comprehension* will do, converting each inner array to a tuple before passing it to the dict for lookup:

```
>>> out = [a[tuple(x)] for x in b]
>>> out
['Car', 'Traffic Light', 'Pedestrian']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the string using a tuple as a key. The reason you can't use a list as a key is because lists can be modified, and you wouldn't other spots in your code modifying your dictionary keys.

```
>>> a[[1,1,0,0]] # Won't work because it's not a tuple
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

>>> a[(1,1,0,0)] # Works
'Car'
```

If you want to use the list as a key, then you can convert it

```
>>> a[tuple([1,1,0,0])]
'Car'
```

If you have a list of arrays (like in your example) then you can grab all their matching strings like this

```
>>> b=np.array([[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]])
>>> [a[tuple(eachList)] for eachList in b]
['Car','Traffic Light','Pedestrian']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking after efficiency if `b` is a big array,  transform it in hashable keys :

```
B=(b<<np.arange(4)).sum(1)
# array([3, 1, 8], dtype=int32)
```

Then define dict as :

```
A={1: 'Traffic Light', 3: 'Car', 8: 'Pedestrian'}
```

The mapping  now can be:

```
[A[key] for key in B]
```